# Weblogic 12c JMX Session Management

Tags: weblogic, jmx, weblogic12c

I'm trying to write some JMX code to manage Weblogic sessions. Ideally, what I'd like to be able to do is to find a session based on some attribute in the session and then be able to invalidate that session. However, I haven't been able to figure out if there is anything that I can do to accomplish this. Using the `DomainRuntimeServiceMBean` I can drill down and get the `WebAppComponentRuntimeMBean`. From there I can get sessions either by session id or by monitoring id. However, what I want to do is to find a session by some attribute in the session. Say, I have an attribute called "externalSessionId" and I want to be able to find a session with a particular value of this attribute - is that doable?

Comment: I'm afraid your only solution is to iterate all sessions to find the ones with the requested attribute.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin - what's the best way to get a hold of all of the sessions and their data? WebAppComponentRuntimeMBean.getServletSessions() has been deprecated and I didn't see another way to actually get the internal session data, but I'm probably overlooking something.

Comment: For security reasons, reading http sessions from jmx has been deprecated. I'm not surprised you do not find any way to look into http sessions outside the web container.
Another way is to generate and analyze a heap-dump.